# Set web package destination folder in TFS 2010 build definition

Tags: msdeploy

We have to web projects that we want to generate web deploy packages for on nightly build.
One MVC2 project and on WCF project.

We have a script that listens for new versions of these packages and deploys them as there are dropped new versions. The problem with this is that the packages gets deployed inside the TFS deploy folders, i.e. '....\Nightly Build_20101021.3_PublishedWebSites'.

Is there any way to define a set path for the deployment of the web deploy packages, 
i.e.'....\NightlyBuild\packages'?
Can we do this in the build definition?

Our MSBUild arguments for the build defintion are: 
/P:CreatePackageOnPublish=true /P:DeployOnBuild=true

We use TFS2010 and visual studio 2010 in the project.

Cheers,

Cooper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this by following the guide in this article:

http://nickhoggard.wordpress.com/tag/continuous-integration/

Adding the copy directory task as mentioned towards the end of the article did the trick.